# Editing my Ionic Config Breaks the Config Forever

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic2

So, I'm attempting to update my proxies in Ionic to get around any CORS problems. The weird issue is, whenever I update my Ionic config, it is forever broken afterwards. This is what the is generated from a fresh `Ionic Start` command

```
{
 "name": "vsts",
 "app_id": "",
 "type": "ionic-angular",
 "integrations": {}
}
```

Running `Ionic Serve` with this setup causes no initial issues. So then my next step is to add the proxy

```
{
 "name": "vsts",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {},
  "proxies": [
  {
     "path": "/api",
     "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
  }
 ]
}
```

which then results in

```
[ERROR] The config file (.\ionic.config.json) is not valid JSON format.


    Please fix any JSON errors in the file.
```

I have ran this through JSONLint and my eyes don't deceive me, that is valid JSON. My next thought was to revert it back to the original JSON, but every subsequent attempt to run `Ionic Serve` results in it telling me that the JSON is not valid. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Is your ```ionic.config.json``` at the root level? where ```package.json``` is? Trying running ```ionic-app-scripts serve -b```

Comment: Ionic config and package were both at root. Running ionic-app-scripts serve -b made the project start looking for the main ts under src/app instead of src for some reason... And then I restarted the project(which I've done before), and it started working just fine... Should I delete this question. as I don't have an answer for why that happened? @SumamaWaheed